# Windows 7 : snipping tool is gone

Tags: windows-7, snipping

I have windows 7 ultimate build 7600,but i can't seem to find the snipping tool anywhere

It used to be there,but i can't find it anymore,I tried the start menu search,but no use

it's not even in the accessories menu

I also tried to reinstall the "tablet PC" part in "windows features" but that also didn't work

what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recreate a shortcut to it in the Start Menu. The target is `%windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe`.

Maybe it was inadvertently removed?

Comment: I found it inside that directory,made a shortcut to it on the desktop,thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you like snipping tools ... have you looked at [Lightscreen Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/lightscreen_portable)

> Lightscreen Portable
>   your tool for screenshots
>   Lightscreen Portable is an easy to use screenshot app packaged as a portable app so you can take pictures of the current in-use desktop wherever you go. You can place it on your USB flash drive, iPod, portable hard drive or a CD and use it on any computer, without leaving any personal information behind.